# Jquery countdown timezone

Tags: jquery, timer, timezone, countdown

I am using this [jQuery countdown plugin](https://github.com/zackperdue/Countdown.git)

This is the [js file](https://github.com/zackperdue/Countdown/blob/master/jquery.countdown.js)

I want to know if this plugin automatically set the timezone based on whichever country you are in.

Comment: It's a countdown to a specific point in time. Are you saying you want the 'blast-off' to be different across timezones?

Comment: I want to make sure the timer is working based on the viewer local time. Sorry if it is and this is a silly question.

Answer (score 1):

Since he's using the Javascript Date object, the answer is yes. Time calculations use the timezone of the machine running the browser.

(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)